# Check if method is invokable in Qt

Tags: c++, qt5, qmetaobject

My Qt5/C++ program creates a method name (string) on the fly and then if the method is invokable will call it (using invokemethod).  And if not invokable/does not exist, then it will no attempt to invoke it.  My methods would be defined like this:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void m1();
void m2();
Q_INVOKABLE void m3();
```

So m1 and m3 would be directly invokable using "invokemethod".  But m2 would not.  Since my code will determine on the fly which method to invoke (creating a string with the method name), I need to test if a method is invokable at runtime.  How can I do that?  I want something like:

```
bool invokable = QMetaObject::isInvokable(classptr,"m2");
```

would return false,

```
bool invokable = QMetaObject::isInvokable(classptr,"m1");
```

would return true,

```
bool invokable = QMetaObject::isInvokable(classptr,"nosuchmethod");
```

would return false.  I found a method called:

```
int QMetaObject::indexOfMethod(const char *method) const
```

But it doesn't seem to care about the class, just the method name.  How can that be usefull, some class A might have an "M1" defined will class B might not have an "M1" method defined.

Comment: `QMetaObject::indexOfMethod` perhaps.

Comment: Please note I expanded the question to cover indexOfMethod - still not clear how that could be used if multiple classes have/don't have identically named methods.  Can you answer with an example.

Comment: @TSG `indexOfMethod()` is not `static` so no need to specify the class since you already call the function for an actual instance.

Comment: `indexOfMethod` is a non-static member, it acts on a particular instance of `QMetaObject` describing a particular class.

Comment: I'm still not clear how to call it.  Do I have to make a QMetaObject instance first?  How do I pass my class ptr?  Does my class have to inherit from QMetaObject?  Still struggling to connect the dots.  Could you answer with sample code?

Comment: @TSG For each `QObject`,  a `QMetaObject` is created and accessible through `QObject::metaObject()` [as you can read it here in the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmetaobject.html#details:~:text=A%20single%20QMetaObject%20instance%20is%20created%20for%20each%20QObject%20subclass%20that%20is%20used%20in%20an%20application%2C%20and%20this%20instance%20stores%20all%20the%20meta%2Dinformation%20for%20the%20QObject%20subclass.%20This%20object%20is%20available%20as%20QObject%3A%3AmetaObject().).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such function available but you can easily write your own by taking advantage of [`QMetaObject::indexOfMethod()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmetaobject.html#indexOfMethod) (as proposed by [*@Igor Tandetnik*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75246955/check-if-method-is-invokable-in-qt#comment132781134_75246955)).

It returns `-1` if the method is not found (it returns its index otherwise).

Something like:

```
bool isInvokable(QObject * obj, const char * method)
{
    return obj->metaObject()->indexOfMethod(method) != -1;
}
```

Comment: Don't you think that `if (somthing) return false; else return true;` is code mumbling?

Comment: @MarekR You're right, I wrote faster than my mind could follow XD Corrected

Comment: But it's a good simple answer to the question (the reader can use it more intelligently)